# How to use zener diode for negative voltages?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, zener

Every one may be familiar with zener diode function in positive voltages but I don't know how to use them in negative voltages.

For example in the schematic below, if we use a 10v zener and the input voltage is around 12v, we can expect a rather 10v output, but if we reverse it for a negative voltage as in schematic number 2 ( ground is now a positive voltage compared to -12v), all we get is power dissipation ( because it tries to bring down the ground voltage and as it is impossible, the diode just starts getting hot). What is the correct design for using a zener for negative voltages?

1- Positive Voltage:

[image: Positive Volatge:]

2- Negative Voltage:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use your first diagram, substitute -12V for the +12V source and *turn the Zener diode around the other way*, you'll get a regulated -10V at the output node.

With your second diagram, the output node will be regulated to 10V above the -12V source, for a net value of -2V, which is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

To amplify Dave Tweed's correct answer, note that the second diagram can be redrawn as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGUmYs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But, you want the output voltage to be taken from across the zener diode (after all, the voltage across the diode is what is approximately constant!) and *not* the resistor.

The correct circuit is, as Dave Tweed remarks:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIoSs5.png)</sup>

Now, the output voltage is across the zener diode and is equal to \$ -V_Z \$